# need some tutorials on Grails Shiro Security

Tags: grails, shiro

hey all 
i need some good tutorials demonstrating all the aspects of grails shiro securty, that how to use them using some example.
i already have read the tutorials explained in grails site but i need some tutorials with examples. 
Please help friends...

m waiting for some positive response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the shiro-plugin is great regarding it's functionality, but not too well documented - I agree.
So I guess you will not find any additional tutorials beyond what you already know.

As with most of the plugins, they are mostly simple wrappers around the main library, so a good start to understand shiro is the shiro documentation.

Next problem is to understand how Peter Ledbrook mapped the shiro functionality to grails features. For me, the most important thing was that shiro methods like `SecurityUtils.subject.isPermitted` are mapped to the methods you'll find in the realm. By modifying the realm file, you'll be able to do nearly all tricks you need to do (for instance get some permissions through LDAP).

If you could be more specific on what you need to know about shiro in detail, maybe I could give you a better answer :-)

Comment: Thanks Ralf i would definetly ask you if for any query regarding shiro. since right now i just need some more tutorials.. if you find any please do provide me.. on this Postt. Thanks alot..

Comment: Dear Ralf .please guide me that i have 2 methods in my Controller one is login and second is logout. and 1 role 'user' defined in my DB and i have a user with that role. now what i want to do is that person can login but could not access the logout button. how can i add permission/restrictions that would allow that user not to Logout.

Comment: The best way would be to add permissions to the role 'user'. The right permission would be 'myController:login'. role.addToPermissions('myController:login') . for this to work, you need the code from the plugin Description, section "Access control by convention". Please open new questions for questions like this - I will watch for them and try to answer them timely.

Comment: It could be that you need to execute shiro-quick-start and/or create-wildcard-realm too in order to make it work. If you repost your question, I will be able to copy and paste code fragments.

Comment: as told i have posted this Query as a new Question. Please check on it. and do provide me with some Code Snippets that could help me in this. :) please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5815189/521015

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the nimble plugin (http://www.grails.org/plugin/nimble). It uses Shiro and would probably be a good example.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Nimble is no longer maintained.

Comment: @JasonGritman - The all new nimble is already there and very well maintained

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample app on the [Grails site](http://www.grails.org/Sample+Applications) you just need to check out.

another one is [here](http://grails.org/Tutorials) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-apacheshiro/) and some [Videos](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&biw=1680&bih=931&tbm=vid&q=grails++example&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&bav=on.2,or.&fp=e94c78e7a66667ea) on google

Comment: i already have seen those examples but need some more examples the secong example you mentioned is not for grails. and there are no videos regarding grails shiro security

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I actually had the same question today and following Ralf answer lead me here: http://shiro.apache.org/10-minute-tutorial.html, which I think is the best place to start