# how to restrict action in grails shiro security

Tags: grails, shiro

.please guide me that i have 2 methods in my Controller one is login and second is logout. and 1 role 'user' defined in my DB and i have a user with that role. now what i want to do is that person can login but could not access the logout button. how can i add permission/restrictions that would allow that user not to Logout.

Comment: Why in the world would you not want to allow a user to logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815401/how-to-implement-shiro-security-of-grails-in-my-project) and use `roleUser.addToPermissions('auth:login,signIn')` as permission. This adds the permissions as described in your question: only login is allowed, logout is not in the list and thus not allowed. We have to state not only `login` which will show the login screen, but also `signIn` which is the action of the actual sign in.